# Spring Data JPA with Security EvaluationContextExtensionSupport not working

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I wanted to use Spring Data JPA's Security Extension support to perform a check on user's authority and accordingly fetch some values. I'm trying to do this as indicated [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Below is my code snippet

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "ProductStatus", path = "ProductStatus")
    public interface IProductStatusRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductStatusEntity, String> {
        @Query("SELECT p FROM ProductStatusEntity " +
                "?#{hasAuthority('ITManager') ? ' ' : ' WHERE ProductStatusCode NOT IN (\'VAL1\',\'VAL2\',\'VAL3\')'}")
        List<ProductStatusEntity> findStatusesByAuthority();
    }
```

I did declare the SecurityEvaluationContextExtension class and securityExtension bean by merely copy pasting the code. But still, the above piece of code doesnt work.

I always get a

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ?
```

I tried several options in playing around with ?#, :#, hasRole, hasAuthority etc. Nothing seem to work.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well this one worked after several trial and errors

```
@Query("select p from ProductStatusEntity p where p.productStatusCode NOT IN ( ?#{hasAuthority('ITManager') ? ' ' : @settings.productStatusExceptions})")
List<ProductStatusEntity> findStatusesByAuthority();
```

The problem seems to be that SpEL is only being recognized if there is a WHERE clause specified.. Probably this could be improved.. not sure..